# Move components one at a time with WindowBuilderPro

Tags: windowbuilder

When I move components on a GUI using the WindowBuilderPro visual designer , other components move too and I don't want them to. It wastes time having to move them back. Does anyone know if it's possible to stop this from happening, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is absolute layout, try giving it to the form before placing components down onto it.

Comment: What about changing it now the components are there?

Comment: Try it, If you can go into the code I think you can change it by setting the layout to null. It might re-arrange the components you have already put down because absolute will require x,y co-ordinates of each component and other layouts don't

Comment: No need: I was able to change it in the Design page. That's great. thanks again.Well it's certainly solved the second problem. +1 thanks. I'll accept your answer in 10 mins when it lets me, Godwilling.

Comment: The only probelm is the TextArea which diplays the user instructions doesn't resize dynamically anymore: anyway to fix that you know of?

Comment: Not with absolute layout, no. - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html here you can find documentation for the layouts provided in Java.